# Adding text to a JFrame

Tags: java, jframe

I'm a beginner in java and I've made a Lottery System using JFrame that opens up a window and let's you click a "play" button to run the lottery. Currently your winnings and number are shown in the console as I've been unable to find a way to display text in my JFrame even though I've searched quite a bit I always get errors that I cannot fix or simply get no working results. (As mentioned I'm a beginner)

What I'm trying to achieve is basically a table or a block of text that tells you your possible winnings and what numbers will give what winnings.
Also an area in which your number and your winnings is displayed after each time the "play" button is pressed.

I'm not looking for anything super fancy, just something that works basically, as I am a beginner.

So this is what it looks like as of now:

http://i.gyazo.com/1ffda0067a033bd6d5fd92dbf6bc8fed.png

The system consists of 2 files, this is what they look like:

LotteryMain.java

```
public class LotteryMain {
/**
 **@author Samy
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    TheLottery n = new TheLottery();
    n.TheLottery();

}
}
```

TheLottery.java

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TheLottery extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
/**
 **author Samy
 */
JFrame frame = new JFrame("The Lottery");
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
JButton play = new JButton("Play");

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;



public void TheLottery() {




    int width = 720;
    int height = width/16*9;

    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(width,height);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.add(panel);

    panel.add(play);



    play.addActionListener(this);


    play.setToolTipText("Click me to play the lottery!");




}


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    Object action = e.getSource();

    String winnings;
    double lotteryChance = Math.random()*100;

    if(action == play) {

        if (lotteryChance > 50) {
            winnings = ("You've won $100!");
        } else if (lotteryChance < 50 && lotteryChance > 20) {
            winnings = ("You've won $500!");
        } else if (lotteryChance < 20 && lotteryChance > 5) {
            winnings = ("You've won $2,000!");
        } else if (lotteryChance < 5 && lotteryChance > 1) {
            winnings = ("You've won $5,000!");
        } else if (lotteryChance < 1 && lotteryChance > 0.1) {
            winnings = ("You've won $25,000!");
        } else if (lotteryChance < 0.1 && lotteryChance > 0.01) {
            winnings = ("You've won $50,000!");
        } else if (lotteryChance < 0.01 && lotteryChance > 0.001) {
            winnings = ("You've won $250,000!");
        } else if (lotteryChance < 0.001 && lotteryChance > 0) {
            winnings = ("YOU'VE WON THE JACKPOT! $1,000,000!!!");
        } else winnings = ("Something went wrong, no winnings this round.");

        System.out.println("Your number is: "+lotteryChance);
        System.out.println(winnings);

    }   
}
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT: How can I add a piece of text that changes every time I run the lottery?

Comment: Call `frame.setVisible(true)` in the end after adding all the components.

Comment: @Braj:thats what is in my answer

Comment: but as per title you want to add text in JFrame that can be achieved by JLabel.

Comment: If you look at the picture all the elements he added (the play button, which is added after `frame.setVisible(true)`) are already visible, you don't need to set the frame to visible twice

Comment: @Zach I am not telling to add it twice. Just add it once but in the last otherwise some time components will not be visible until frame is resized.

Comment: @Zach I have already given +1 for your answer. :)

Comment: @Braj I don't think it matters whether you set the frame to visible before or after you add the panel and the components, but I may be wrong. If you look at the code he is doing it in the "wrong" order but if you look at the picture it looks like all the components were successfully added and displayed. Please correct me if I'm wrong though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is a [JLabel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html)

JLabels display some text that is defined by you:

```
String winnings = "You've won $200!";
JLabel label = new JLabel(winnings);
panel.add(label);
```

Then, whenever the winnings change, you can update it like so:

```
winnings = "You've won $1,000"; // Winnings changed
label.setText(winnings);
```

Comment: The "winnings" variable is a string which is already defined in the actionPerformed void, I'm confused on how I would use this.

Comment: Oh, I'll edit in how to use it with a String for you, its not very different

Comment: I already solved this and have come across a few different issues, but if you'd like to help me with those too I'd much appreciate it :)
link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24843611/how-to-move-jbuttons-and-jlabels-position-in-a-jpanel-jframe

Comment: Alright, but if you find my answer to answer the question, you should mark it as correct, I'll have a look at the other question now :).

Comment: Actually, none of the answers answered my question, I just sort of read through the comments and stuff and eventually figured out how to solve it, but I'll put your answer as the correct one because I think it was the most helpfull :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the general way

using a [**JLabel**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html)

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JPanel panel= new JPanel();
JLabel label= new JLabel();
label.setText("test");
panel.add(label);
frame.add(main);
frame.pack();
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: call `frame.pack()` instead of calling `frame.setSize()`. ``pack()` fits the components based on components preferred size.

Comment: @Braj: i have edited my answer after your suggestion,thank you

Comment: why you are calling `setUndecorated()`? what is purpose of this line?

Comment: @Braj Disables or enables decorations for this frame.

Comment: @Braj:actually no need of that,i will remove it