# How to move JButtons and JLabels position in a JPanel, JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jlabel, layout-manager

I am creating a simple lottery as a practice, I am a beginner of Java. I have achieved almost everything that I want apart from one thing: Moving the different texts and buttons to the position that I'd like them to be.

Here is a picture edited in Photoshop  describing how I would like it to be:

[image: http://i.gyazo.com/9587eb7e451b90ea0f920c4795a03cd5.png]

The Lottery currently looks like this after you press the Play button:

(As you can see the buttons get shifted to the right in order to make space for the text that is squished in to the left of the buttons)

[image]

What I'm looking to achieve is for the buttons position to never move, and to put the text under the buttons.

I would also like to add a table that describes your potential winnings and what number will give you what winnings.

The code consists of 2 Java Classes, and please remember that I am a beginner and if you see any simple room for improvement (I know there must be plenty) I would be glad if you gave me a tips or anything :)

So this is the code:

LotteryMain.Java

```
public class LotteryMain {
/**
 **@author Samy
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    TheLottery n = new TheLottery();
    n.TheLottery();

}
}
```

TheLottery.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;

public class TheLottery extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
/**
 **author Samy
 */

JFrame frame = new JFrame("The Lottery");
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
JButton play = new JButton("Play");
JButton exit = new JButton("Exit");
JLabel label = new JLabel();

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;



public void TheLottery() {


    panel.add(label);

    int width = 720;
    int height = width/16*9;

    frame.setSize(width,height);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setUndecorated(true);
    frame.add(panel);

    panel.setBackground(new Color(0x222222));
    panel.setBorder(new EtchedBorder(new Color(0xAAAAAA),new Color(0x666666)));
    panel.add(play);
    panel.add(exit);



    play.addActionListener(this);
    exit.addActionListener(this);

    play.setToolTipText("Click me to play the lottery!");
    exit.setToolTipText("Click me to exit.");

    frame.setVisible(true);

}



@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    Object action = e.getSource();

    String winnings = null;
    double lotteryChance = Math.random()*100;

    if(action == play) {

        if (lotteryChance > 80) {
            winnings = ("You lost! Luckily this lottery is free to play.");
        } else if (lotteryChance < 80 && lotteryChance > 50) {
            winnings = ("You've won $100!");
        } else if (lotteryChance < 50 && lotteryChance > 20) {
            winnings = ("You've won $500!");
        } else if (lotteryChance < 20 && lotteryChance > 5) {
            winnings = ("You've won $2,000!");
        } else if (lotteryChance < 5 && lotteryChance > 1) {
            winnings = ("You've won $5,000!");
        } else if (lotteryChance < 1 && lotteryChance > 0.1) {
            winnings = ("You've won $25,000!");
        } else if (lotteryChance < 0.1 && lotteryChance > 0.01) {
            winnings = ("You've won $50,000!");
        } else if (lotteryChance < 0.01 && lotteryChance > 0.001) {
            winnings = ("You've won $250,000!");
        } else if (lotteryChance < 0.001 && lotteryChance > 0) {
            winnings = ("YOU'VE WON THE JACKPOT OF $1,000,000!");
        } else winnings = ("Something went wrong, no winnings this round.");


        System.out.println("Your number is: "+lotteryChance);
        System.out.println(winnings);   
    }   
    if(action == exit) {
        System.exit(1);
    }
    label.setText("<html><font color='white'>Your number is: "+lotteryChance+" -                                               "+winnings+"</font></html>");

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a FlowLayout, which rearranges items automatically based on their sizes and the window size, you can use a BorderLayout or GridLayout. A BorderLayout basically splits the window into 5 areas, each border is a separate area identified with a cardinal direction (north, east, etc.), and the center is it's own area as well. A GridLayout allows you to specify if you want a particular number of rows/columns, while letting the other expand as necessary (n elements into 2 columns, for example).

From the look of your photoshopped desired outcome, you can use a BorderLayout for the main frame, with the buttons in the north, the number/results in the center, and the table in the south. Also remember that you can put a panel in a layout area, with that panel having its own layout, such as a GridLayout for the buttons in the north, or even better, for the table in the south. Hope that helps!

Some code to assist you:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("The Lottery");
JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

JPanel northPanel = new JPanel();
JButton play = new JButton("Play");
JButton exit = new JButton("Exit");
northPanel.add(play);
northPanel.add(exit);
mainPanel.add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

Comment: I tried this but how can I make the buttons share the northern area? When I do this the Exit button simply covers the Play one so that all you can do is exit. And I don't want to put one button in the north and one in the south, even though it worked it was very ugly :/

Comment: This is a picture of the best I can achieve with Border Layout. I think anyways, let me know if I'm wrong please. http://gyazo.com/29a2f9af8af80cd2e7d875c11c0c7762

Comment: You can add a panel in the northern area, then add the buttons to that panel. It will default to a FlowLayout, which should work properly when you add multiple buttons to it.

Comment: How would I do that? I am really a beginner and needed tutorials to get to where I was before I made this post.

Comment: I read the code you added and I found it quite helpfull, I managed to achieve this: http://i.gyazo.com/5a3d2961a0775db35037207b66c6a818.png
Thanks for the help! Also, I'm wondering if you know how I could put the lines of text above each other as they currently cover each other. They are 2 different labels located in the Center of the Border Layout but as you can see the 2nd one covers the 1st one so you can't see the "winnings", only the number part.

Comment: You can do the same thing with the JLabels. Make a new JPanel, call it centerPanel or whatever you want, add the two JLabels to it, and then use mainPanel.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER).

Comment: Oh right, but with flow layout I end up with the 2 lines of text after each other, and I want them to be above and below each other, do you any way of easily moving on label under the other inside a panel? And thanks again for the help btw :)

Comment: Ok so for the centerPanel you can set it to GridLayout(2,1). That basically says you want it in 2 rows and 1 column. If you wanted it in one column but you didn't know how many rows, you could do GridLayout(0,1) and you can do the same thing if you want it in a certain number of rows but don't know how many columns. One of them has to be greater than 0, you can't make a GridLayout(0,0). Hope this helps

Comment: Hi again! I tried your way with gridlayout and TECHNICALLY it worked, it did put the lines above eachother, but it made the space between them (vertically) HUGE, and they were aligned to the right. I wanted them centered. So I went back to the flow layout and I found a way to put both the labels into 1 label and using HTML cause a break between them, creating a new line. I got it working now, if you want I can show you the code I used and the result, maybe you'll learn something too :) Anyways, thanks again for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

> What I'm looking to achieve is for the buttons position to never move, and to put the text under the buttons.

`JPanel` by default use `FlowLayout` that adds the component one after another. You can use multiple `JPanel` as well and add in another ``JPanel`.

If you want to display text below the button then use `BorderLayout` or `GridBagLayout`.

It's worth reading *Swing Tutorial* on [How to Use Various Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/layoutlist.html)

Sample code:

```
JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
topPanel.add(new JButton("Play"));
topPanel.add(new JButton("Exit"));

JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
panel.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
panel.add(new JLabel("Hello", JLabel.CENTER));
```

snapshot:

[image]

Comment: I could not get this to work with my code, how would I apply it?

Comment: spend some time on reading about layout manager. It takes time to learn new things.

Comment: I managed to achieve this with border layout: http://gyazo.com/29a2f9af8af80cd2e7d875c11c0c7762 Any tips on how I could put a table of winnings/chances etc in there?